# xml change side by side elements

Tags: android-layout, android-xml

I have this xml. The problem is the things are side by side and I'd like they this way:

```
CircleImageView - shareName // line break
shareTextViewPublisher // line break
shareimageViewHero // line break
```

but they are all in the same line. how to do this?

```
<LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/shareTable"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="50dp"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:background="@drawable/border"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


                    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                    android:layout_width="35dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:id="@+id/sharePic"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="1dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/shareName"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="1dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/shareTextViewPublisher"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:paddingTop="10dp"
                        />


                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:padding="0dp"
                    android:id="@+id/shareimageViewHero"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

            </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I think you simply need to nest 3 horizontal linear layouts in a vertical one

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this using `LinearLayout` you should put your `CircleImageView` and `shareName` in additional horizontal `LinearLayout`. The structure of the XML should like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/shareTable"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="50dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:id="@+id/sharePic"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="1dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/shareName"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/shareTextViewPublisher"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/shareimageViewHero"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

</LinearLayout>
```